# XQuery file:write only writes one line

Tags: xquery, basex

I would like the below query to write the results to an xml file. Currently it only writes the first element of the result into the xml file, regardless of how many elements there are.

Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

```
let $fName := "C:\Users\user\Documents\Sitemaps\Updated Pages\Books.xml"

for $x in doc("http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/books.xml")/bookstore/book
where $x/price>0
return file:write($fName,$x/title)
```

Comment: FYI, StackSnippets are only for code that can be executed in a browser (typically, JavaScript/CSS/etc). For XQuery, you should use the `{}` button in the StackOverflow editor for regular code formating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`file:write()` is not a feature of the standard language, and it relies on side-effects, so the effect is likely to depend on which XQuery processor you are using. You haven't even shown the namespace declaration, so we can't tell whether this is supposed to be a call on the EXPath `file:write()` function.

Assuming it is a call on the EXPath [`file:write()`](http://expath.org/spec/file#fn.write) function, then the effect of `file:write()` should be to write the entire file contents, not to append to the file. If you want to append to the file, use [`file:append()`](http://expath.org/spec/file#fn.append). In this situation however, my instinct would be to write all the items to the file in a single operation, that is:

```
let $doc := doc("http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/books.xml")
return file:write($fName, $doc/bookstore/book[price>0]/title)
```

- http://expath.org/spec/file#fn.write
- http://expath.org/spec/file#fn.append

Answer (score 1):

Based on your code I would expect it to write only the *last* title in the document. You don't say which XQuery processor you're using, but it's possible this is an implementation-defined behavior - maybe the equivalent of a "conflicting updates" error.

Wrap your entire query in an XML element (it's invalid to create XML with multiple root nodes), and write that entire document to disk (calling `file:write` only once):

```
file:write($fName,
  element titles {
    for $x in doc("http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/books.xml")/bookstore/book
    where $x/price>0
    return $x/title
  })
```

Answer (score 1):

For BaseX, invoking `file:write()` will overwrite any existing file content. You are invoking it for each item, so the last one will "win".

http://docs.basex.org/wiki/File_Module#file:write

> Writes a serialized sequence of items to the specified file. If the
>   file already exists, it will be overwritten.

You should either change your XQuery to write the sequence of items as @wst suggests, or ensure that each item is written with a unique file URI